# How can I place multiple pages on 1 sheet, without increasing the PDF's file size?

Tags: pdf

I must [convert/print this original PDF of 6.47 MB](https://mega.nz/#!y5BHQIKD!Jt6gmJ9lcuOpNN5jrADUmd1OZBwp1Ulq5CwnbaNqil4) to a shorter PDF, with 2 pages on 1 sheet.  When I used 'Microsoft Print to PDF' in Acrobat, it output [a PDF of 1 GB](https://mega.nz/#!StIznICA!tsbzqUhJppH2gbsOSZFt4LUYHP878_2YXpOvvYsuJHY)! Please see the screenshot below.

[image]

1. How else can I achieve this?
2. Why the behemothic file size? Oughtn't the file size lessen, as I'm printing the same content on half of the pages?

Comment: That sounds like a bug.

Comment: Why not let the user decide on how to handle it? As for the file size increase: Are you still able to select text individually in the 230 MB PDF? If not it might be that every page is converted to a graphic?

Comment: The apostrophe is used to mark code. `Code` between two of them will be highlighted like that. I mean to say why you actually want to do that in a PDF rather than just let the user who's finally printing that document let decide it on the fly for himself. Another option would be to change the original non-pdf version of the document and convert that to PDF.

Comment: @Seth I need the intermediate document to crop out blank space; if I order my printer to print 2 pages on one sheet, it'll print blank space.

Comment: It seems like as much as you've changed, it may have been better to start a new question for the specifics you are after and just link to this question showing based on this and the answers I got here, I now need to know, so and so for Adobe, etc. That makes better sense than changing the question and then adding a new answer based on the new question you edited. Plus took away the accepted vote on the original question and solution you were provided. You can ask many questions here even if they are similar or used an extension of a previous question and answer you asked/received....

Comment: EXCEPT, when you ask EXACTLY THE SAME QUESTION again it will be closed as a duplicate, as it should be. By editing this question you've started wrong, and then you made things even more confusing. Perhaps you should roll this back, give the answer mark back, and then leave this as is. THEN go write a new question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I chanced on the solution myself: use 'Adobe PDF'. But I don't know why this works.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Use [GhostScript](http://ghostscript.com/download/) to reduce the size of PDF documents once they are in the final format you need them while the size is inflated. Download and install [GhostScript](http://ghostscript.com/download/) on a machine to shrink PDF files, then run the below logic to reduce the size of the PDF file from an elevated command prompt.

### Instructions

**Be sure. . .**

1. The **GhostScript** `gswin64c.exe` file points where it's installed on your system
2. The `-sOutputFile="C:\PDFFolder\Reduced\ReducedSize.pdf"` part points to the full path folder and file location where to save the reduced size file
3. The `"C:\PDFFolder\ToReduce\Reduce.pdf"` part directly after #2 points to the full path folder and file location to shrink.

---

```
"C:\Program Files\gs\gs\bin\gswin64c.exe" -sDEVICE=pdfwrite -dNOPAUSE -dBATCH -dPDFSETTINGS=/ebook -sOutputFile="C:\PDFFolder\Reduced\ReducedSize.pdf" "C:\PDFFolder\ToReduce\Reduce.pdf"
```

---

### Further Resources

- [**GhostScript Download**](http://ghostscript.com/download/)
- [**GhostScript - man page**](http://linux.die.net/man/1/gs)

Comment: @Greek-Area51Proposal - Just to be clear, you will run this against the final PDF file once it is in the inflated size and final format. Be sure to look it over with detail and confirm the content is fully there as expected but this process works well for me on most PDF files.

Comment: Thanks! I tried the other solution first: using Adobe Acrobat DC and then printing with Adobe PDF, which helped! What was the final reduced file size for your method? I'll award you the bounty if it's small enough.

Comment: @Greek-Area51Proposal I was not able to download every one of the PDF files and test, but the **Linear Algrebra by Jeff Hefferon** went from 7.3 MB to 2.9 MB so reduced it quite a bit but this was for the whole entire PDF document without merging pages to the same sheet, cutting off at specific chapters, etc. but it works quite well for me nearly always.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the way you process your pdf is by reading it and printing it to pdf, the result you get depends on:

1. The application you use for reading your original (OPDF) pdf,
2. The printer driver you use for generating your two-pages-per-sheet (TPPS) pdf,
3. (Possibly) the respective settings.

For instance: 1) I read GIAM.pdf (from your link) with Adobe Acrobat X Pro, 2) Removed all pages from chapter 2 onwards (to try with a more manageable document), 3) Save as -> Reduced size PDF. This gave me as a starting point an OPDF of size 452kB.

Now, reading my OPDF with Foxit Portable, 
and printing it to `Microsoft print to PDF`, created a TPPS of ca. 8MB.

On the other hand, reading my OPDF with Adobe Acrobat X Pro, 
and printing it to `Adobe PDF`, created a TPPS of ca. 281kB.

If you are not bound to any specific application/printer driver, given that Adobe Acrobat X Pro (the option that worked fine for me) is paid, I would suggest you try other options for the three items above.
I do not have a free recommendation so far.